# classcastexception: java.util.linkedhashmap cannot be cast Gson on custom android roms

Tags: android, json, gson

before you mark this as duplicated a note:
My code works on regular android devices but it gives this exception on devices which installed custom roms

here is sample of my code

```
TypeToken<Vector<Country>> token = new TypeToken<Vector<Country>>(){};
        countryVector  = gson.fromJson(countriesstr, token.getType());
```

where countriesstr contains countries json

(I use this on several objects, I use always put @SerializedName on above the property inside the class I want to serialize and deserialize)

does anyone got any idea why other/custom roms may cause such an error?
I use json to transfer data between activities/fragments caching etc...
and it crashes each time a custom rom trying to deserialize a json with Gson.

Instead of getting the Vector i'm getting vector of linked hashmaps on those devices

For the regular devices I've got no problem at all and everything works fine

Hope someone can clarify or make a suggestion on what can I do in order to solve this issue as for many android users installs custom roms on their devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, instead of using Vector I changed every vector i need to store on gson to ArrayList
this solved my problem on whole of the devices
have no idea why but it works